# Sorting 2 Lists of Doubles VB.net

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

I have 2 lists of Doubles:

```
Dim rad as New List(Of Double)
Dim phi As New List(Of Double)
```

Those lists contain values in polar coordinates and are **linked to each other**, which means rad(0) belongs to phi(0) and so on.

I want to sort the numbers according to the radius, so I can try

```
rad.Sort()
```

but that would mean that rad(0) does not belong to phi(0) anymore. Is there an elegant way to link the entries and sort them according to the radius?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Use, e.g., a `List(Of Class)` (with two properties) instead of two `List(Of Double)`?

Comment: @Jimi or even a `List(Of (rad As Double, phi As Double))`.

Comment: Thank you very much, still learning to beat VB :-)

Comment: @Craig What about a `HashSet(Of Structure)`? (In case duplicate values need to be *absorbed* and discarded automatically)

Comment: @Jimi Sure, that could make sense for some use cases, although I don't think it would make sense for the request here since it wouldn't be sorted.  Maybe a `SortedSet`.  (And it should be noted that to the best of my knowledge, a value tuple such as I suggested is a `Structure`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers. Unfortunately, I couldn't use them, I think they were too complicated for me. Here is my solution after some deeper research:

```
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("ColumnRAD", GetType(Double))
        dt.Columns.Add("ColumnPHI", GetType(Double))


        For i = 0 To rad.Count - 1
            dt.Rows.Add(rad(i), phi(i))
        Next

        rad.Clear()
        phi.Clear()


        Dim dfv As DataView = dt.DefaultView
        dfv.Sort = "ColumnRAD ASC"
        Dim dtnew As DataTable = dfv.ToTable()


        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            rad.Add(dtnew.Rows(i)(0))
            phi.Add(dtnew.Rows(i)(1))
        Next
```

This code reads two lists of Doubles and sorts them with ascending radius while the entries are linked. Also it clears the lists because after that, it will add the the new Data back to these original lists.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jimi's comment.

**A class**

```
Private Class PolarCoord
    Public rad As Double
    Public phi As Double
    ''' <summary>
    ''' 
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="r">rad</param>
    ''' <param name="p">phi</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(r As Double, p As Double)
        Me.rad = r
        Me.phi = p
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Usage**

```
    Dim PClist As New List(Of PolarCoord)
    'some sample data
    For Each r As Double In {1.0#, 3.0#, 2.0#, 9.0#, 7.0#}
        Dim pc As New PolarCoord(r, r / 2)
        PClist.Add(pc)
    Next
    'and then sort
    PClist = PClist.OrderBy(Function(pc) pc.rad).ToList 'sort
```

Comment: I'd recommend to expose `rad` and `phi` as `ReadOnly Property` instead of read-write fields.  It would probably also make sense for it to be a `Structure` since it's likely that only the value matters and not individual class identity.